# Link between Univalence & Conformality

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, conformal-geometry

I am familiar with the definition that a holomorphic function is a conformal mapping of some domain if it has non-zero derivative on that domain (as this is an equivalence with angle-preserving).

However, working through some books there seems to be an equivalence between this definition of conformal map and a holomorphic univalent function.

Can someone please shed some insight on this for me?

Is it necessary that a holomorphic univalent function must have non-zero derivative?
Or do we need it to also be surjective?

I don't think that the non-zero derivative definition implies univalence, but again please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Local univalence equivalent conformality but globally while univalent implies conformal, conversely is not true as $e^z$ is conformal but not univalent in general, only locally univalent

Comment: There are two inequivalent definitions of conformality in the literature. Which one do you use?

Comment: Then it is a nice exercise in CA to prove that a univalent function is the same thing as an injective conformal map.

Answer (score 1):

Taking definition that $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ is conformal if $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$ with the property $f'(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \in \Omega$ (where $\Omega$ is an open subset of the complex plane), we have the following:
$$f\text{ is univalent} \implies f \text{ is conformal} $$

$\textbf{Proof} $

Let $f$ be a univalent function on $\Omega$. Thus, $f$ is holomorphic and so we can consider the power series expansion$$f(z) = f(z_0) + f'(z_0)(z-z_0)+\dots$$ locally for some $z_0 \in \Omega$. It is easy now to see that this injectivity implies $f'(z_0)\neq 0$, as if we had a vanishing derivative then we would have $f(z)=f(z_0)$ for distinct $z, z_0 \in \Omega$. Since $z_0 \in \Omega$ was arbitrary, we see univalence implies conformality across $\Omega$.